# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: gradient-descent, numpy

I am doing multiple linear regression using gradient descent and am getting this type-error

```
X = adds[['TV','Radio','Newspaper']]
y = np.array(adds[['Sales']]).reshape(1,200)

def hypothesis_func(theta,X,n):
   h = np.ones((X.shape[0],1),dtype=object)
   theta = theta.reshape(1,n+1)
   for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
       h[i] = float(np.vdot(theta,X[i])) #Matrix product of two arrays.
   h = h.reshape(X.shape[0])
   return h

def batch_gradient_descent(theta,alpha,iterations,h,n,X,y):
    cost = np.ones(iterations)
    m = y.size
    for i in range(0,iterations):
        theta[0] = theta[0] - (alpha/m) * sum(h-y)
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha/m) * sum((h-y)*(X.transpose()[j]))
        h = hypothesis_func(theta,X,n)
        cost[i] = 1/(2*m) * sum(np.square(h-y))
   theta = theta.reshape(1,n+1)
   return theta,cost

# Set hyperparameters
alpha = 0.0001
iterations = 10000

n = X.shape[1]
one_column = np.ones((X.shape[0],1)) 
X = np.concatenate((one_column,X),axis=1) # adding 1s column to X

theta = np.zeros((n+1),dtype=object)

h = hypothesis_func(theta,X,n)

theta,cost = batch_gradient_descent(theta,alpha,iterations,h,n,X,y)
theta,cost
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-431-25f0309cea37> in <module>
----> 1 theta,cost = batch_gradient_descent(theta,alpha,iterations,h,n,X,y)
      2 theta,cost

<ipython-input-429-bf15764a7911> in batch_gradient_descent(theta, alpha, iterations, h, n, X, y)
      6         for j in range(1,n+1):
      7             theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha/m) * sum((h-y)*(X.transpose()[j]))
----> 8         h = hypothesis_func(theta,X,n)
      9         cost[i] = 1/(2*m) * sum(np.square(h-y))
     10     theta = theta.reshape(1,n+1)

<ipython-input-428-10238552e56d> in hypothesis_func(theta, X, n)
      3     theta = theta.reshape(1,n+1)
      4     for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
----> 5         h[i] = float(np.vdot(theta,X[i])) #Matrix product of two arrays.
      6     h = h.reshape(X.shape[0])
      7     return h

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```